# Don't want to focus input field after closed the bootstrap modal in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular-ui-bootstrap, internet-explorer-10

When I closing the bootstrap modal, text cursor is automatically placed in any of the input fields in a page. It is happening only in internet explorer 10. I don't need to focus the cursor on any of the input fields after closing the modal. Instead of that, place the focus on the element (where click happened for opening the modal) after modal closed. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

How about just calling this after your modal is closed;

`$('input').blur();`